# Sources not included when exporting build definition

Tags: tfs

I am using the TFS 2018 SDK to read and export all my build definitions to json files for backup.

```
internal void ExportBuildDefinitions(List<BuildDefinition> defs)
{
            var dir = Directory.CreateDirectory("JSON_" + DateTime.Now.Ticks);

            foreach (var def in defs)
            {
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                    def,
                    Formatting.Indented,
                    new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore });

                File.WriteAllText($"{dir}/{def.Id}.json", json);
            }
 }
```

Most of the work involves in setting manually the dependent sources in the build definition. But it looks like the sources are not included when exporting the build definition. How can I also include the sources?

Comment: What's that mean for "`work involves in setting manually the dependent sources` " ? Can you see the sources when export the definition from web portal? Also with the [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/definitions#get-a-build-definition) directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afriad that we can not include the sources if the json file which exported from web interface or get from the REST API also doesn't include them.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Do you know if there is a way to get the sources from the api?

Comment: @doorman No, if we can not retrieve the sources with the official API, then means it's not supported at current time. Maybe you can submit an [user voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services) to suggest the feature.

Comment: Ok thanks, it would be nice to have. I was playing around with the api and I removed all the build defs because I had generated many during tests. I assumed the sources where part of the json file I exported :s so I had to reenter all the sources. I think it would be convenient to be able to export the sources and to easily be able to remove all defs and restore them as needed.

Comment: @doorman Actually I still confused with the "`Sources`" you mentioned, the build sources (repository mappings serverPath) is included in the exported json file. So, could you please clarify what's the exact `sources` you mentioned here? Then we can suggest feature accordingly.

Comment: Hi Andy, I will have a better look and let you know. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Andy, you where right the mappings are included under the repostiory.properties property. Thanks!